# Typing a Generic Callable Bug

Tags: python, python-typing

For some reason the callable cannot be typed correctly. The following code throws errors in Pylance and mypy.

### Example Code

So if all of these invariant, covariant and contravariant throw an exception. How can a `Callable` be generically typed?

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Any, Callable

class BaseModel:
    ...

class Model(BaseModel):
    ...

_T = TypeVar("_T")
_T_co = TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)
_T_contra = TypeVar("_T_contra", contravariant=True)

class Dispatcher(Generic[_T, _T_co, _T_contra]):
    def add_callback(self, func: Callable[[_T], Any]) -> None:
        ...

    def add_callback_co(self, func: Callable[[_T_co], Any]) -> None:
        ...

    def add_callback_contra(self, func: Callable[[_T_contra], Any]) -> None:
        ...

    def add_mod(self, mod: _T) -> None:
        ...

module_dispatcher: Dispatcher[BaseModel, BaseModel, BaseModel] = Dispatcher()

def call_me(model: Model) -> None:
    ...

module_dispatcher.add_callback(call_me)  # Throws incompatibility
module_dispatcher.add_callback_co(call_me)  # Throws incompatibility
module_dispatcher.add_callback_contra(call_me)  # Throws incompatibility
module_dispatcher.add_mod(Model())  # This is OK
```

### mypy / pylance output

mypy complains about the `Callable` only. The `add_mod` method does the Generic type inference.

```
/tmp/testing.py:35: error: Argument 1 to "add_callback" of "Dispatcher" has incompatible type "Callable[[MyModel], None]"; expected "Callable[[MyBaseModel], Any]"
```

Comment: Your dispatcher wants callbacks that can accept any instance of `MyBaseModel`. `call_me` only accepts instances of `MyModel`. It's not clear what you were trying to do here.

Comment: Any `call_me` callback added must accept a `Model` which has to be derived from `BaseModel`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the type of functions is contravariant in their argument.

The argument `func` to `module_dispatcher.add_callback` *must* be able to take any instance of `MyBaseModel`.

To see why, note that you could do `module_dispatcher.add_mod(MyOtherModel())` too (assuming `issubclass(MyOtherModel, MyBaseModel)`, of course). Now `call_me` is going to be called with something that is *not* an instance of `MyModel`.

My proposed solution:

```
def call_me(model: MyBaseModel) -> None:
    ...
```

If that doesn't work for you, I'm going to need to know more about the required behaviours of the `Dispatcher` class.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Well, with `call_me(model: BaseModel)` I would not feel comfortable at all doing that. It would subvert the type safety of the code.

Any `call_me` callback added shall accept a `Model` derived from `BaseModel` in its signature.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to be more specific in your question about the requirements of `Dispatcher`, all of its methods, of the callbacks and in particular how these are all meant to work together for me to be able to give you a meaningful answer.